# Insert from another table: Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit

Tags: google-bigquery

Adding additional fields within existing nested column and inserting into staging table, so that I can delete and recreate main table.

Actual rows are not more than 100MB, but causing issue with ARRAY_AGG. I want to do it only using SQL

```
INSERT INTO dev.sessions_16092019 (
  user_session_id
  ,hits
)
SELECT
 MAX(gs.user_session_id)
,ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(gse.page_depth
                 ,gse.page_title
                 ,gse.base_url
                 ,gse.previous_base_url
                 ,gse.short_ref
                 ,gse.parent_short_ref
                 ,gse.visit_start_time_epoch
                 ,gse.visit_start_time_stamp
                 ,gse.hit_timestamp
                 ,gse.hit_time
                 ,gse.hit_time_stamp_epoch
                 ,gse.ga_session_id
                 ,gse.page_path
                 ,gse.criteoid
                 ,gse.fingerprint
                 ,gse.hotel_price
                 ,gse.lvhid
                 ,gse.full_url
                 ,'PAGE'
                 ,'null'
                 ,'null'
                 ,'null'
                 ,null
                           )
          ) as hits
FROM `dev.ga_sessions_15092019_01` gs, unnest(pageviews) gse;
```

Comment: What error was reported exactly?

Comment: Please use the bigquery issue tracker, and make sure to include a job id